# Catch-22 recursive Node modules blowing up when using Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I've been working on a project that uses some custom Node.js modules. I've created a 'helpers' module that assists with loading some helper methods:

**/helpers/index.js:**

```
var mutability = require('./mutability'),
    cb = require('./cb'),
    build = require('./build'),
    userAgent = require('./userAgent'),
    is = require('./is'),
    query = require('./query'),
    config = require('./config'),
    _ = require('underscore')

module.exports = _.extend({
    cb: cb,
    build: build,
    userAgent: userAgent,
    is: is,
    query: query,
    config: config
}, mutability)
```

For fun, `mutability.js` is:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
    setReadOnly: function(obj, key) {
        // whatever
        return obj
    },
    setWritable: function(obj, key) {
        // whatever
        return obj
    }
}
```

One of my modules, `build`, requires a class to do some type checking:

**/helpers/build.js**

```
'use strict'

var urljoin = require('url-join'),
    config = require('./config'),
    cb = require('./cb'),
    Entity = require('../lib/entity'),
    _ = require('underscore')

module.exports = {
    url: function(options) {
        return urljoin(
            config.baseUrl,
            options.client.orgId,
            options.client.appId,
            options.type, (typeof options.uuidOrName === 'string') ? options.uuidOrName : ""
        )
    },
    GET: function(options) {
        options.type = options.type || args[0] instanceof Entity ? args[0]._type : args[0]
        options.query = options.query || args[0] instanceof Entity ? args[0] : undefined
        return options
    }
}
```

And `Entity` then requires `helpers`:

**/lib/entity.js**

```
'use strict'

var helpers = require('../helpers'),
    ok = require('objectkit'),
    _ = require('underscore')

var Entity = function(object) {
    var self = this

    _.extend(self, object)

    helpers.setReadOnly(self, ['uuid'])

    return self
}

module.exports = Entity
```

For whatever reason, when I run this with Mocha, I get `helpers` logging out as `{}` and Mocha throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: helpers.setReadOnly is not a function
```

When I run `/lib/entity.js` directly with `node`, it prints the proper module. What gives? Why is Mocha blowing up?

Comment: That `/helpers/mutability.js` module which you didn't show us seems to be most relevant

Comment: Na, I don't think so. If I require it directly `var mutability = require('/helpers/mutability')` it works just fine. I'm actually leaning towards this being a Mocha bug because it's not *just* mutability that is missing, it's the entire helpers object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the issue is your circular dependency between `index.js` and `entity.js`.

Your dependency graph looks like this (with normalised paths) where each arrow is a `require` statement:

```
/helpers/index.js -> /helpers/build.js -> /lib/entity.js -> /helpers/index.js
```

When a module is `required` in Node `module.exports` is initialised to an empty object.

When you have a circular dependency then it's possible that this default object is returned to another module **before** your code has run to actually set `module.exports = ...;` (because JavaScript is synchronous).

This is what is happening in your case: `/lib/entity.js` is receiving the default exports object from `/helpers/index.js` before index.js has defined it's `module.exports = _.extend(...)`.

To fix it you need to make sure that you extend the same object that has been returned to `/lib/entity.js`, instead of replacing it with a new instance:

```
// Extend `module.exports` instead of replacing it with a new object.
module.exports = _.extend(
    module.exports,
    {
        cb: cb,
        build: build,
        userAgent: userAgent,
        is: is,
        query: query,
        config: config
    },
    mutability
);
```

However, it's generally best to avoid circular dependencies if possible.

Comment: Damn, that's nutty! Makes sense though, thanks for the good suggestion. Normally I wouldn't want circular references, but in this case, given I'm ONLY using it to check type, I think it'll be ok.