# Complex circular Node module dependency throwing "TypeError: The super constructor to 'inherits' must have a prototype"

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I've got a complex Node SDK project that uses some class inheritance to try and static-ify Javascript. I'm using Node's module caching behavior to create a singleton-like behavior for the SDK (the `Project` class, a shared instance of `ProjectClient`). To init, it looks like this:

```
var Project = require('./project'),
Project.init(params)
// Project is now an instance of ProjectClient
```

I've got some object type classes for data as well: `Entity` (a standard parsed JSON payload object) and `User` (a special type of Entity that contains user properties).

The `ProjectClient` class has several methods that allow RESTful API calls to occur, e.g. `Project.GET()`, `Project.PUT()`. These work just fine when instantiating the `Project` "singleton".

I'm now trying to create convenience methods attached to `Entity` that will leverage `ProjectClient`'s RESTful operations, e.g. `Entity.save()`, `Entity.refresh()`.

When I try to import `Project` into the `Entity`:

```
var Project = require('../project')
```

I get:

```
TypeError: The super constructor to `inherits` must have a prototype.
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:756:11)
```

Troubleshooting leads me to this being related to `util.inherits(ProjectUser, ProjectEntity)` in `User`, because if I comment it out, I get this instead:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ProjectEntity is not a function
```

What's going on with `inherits`? why does it think that `Entity` doesn't have a prototype? My best guess is that it's related to the fact that I'm recursively nesting modules within other modules (bad, I know), but I've even tried doing something like this in the various classes but to no avail:

```
module.exports = _.assign(module.exports, **ClassNameHere**)
```

Here's some reduced code for each class:

#### Entity

```
var Project = require('../Project'),
    _ = require('lodash')

var ProjectEntity = function(obj) {
    var self = this

    _.assign(self, obj)

    Object.defineProperty(self, 'isUser', {
        get: function() {
            return (self.type.toLowerCase() === 'user')
        }
    })

    return self
}

module.exports = ProjectEntity
```

#### User (a subclass of Entity)

```
var ProjectEntity = require('./entity'),
    util = require('util'),
    _ = require('lodash')

var ProjectUser = function(obj) {

    if (!ok(obj).has('email') && !ok(obj).has('username')) {
        // This is not a user entity
        throw new Error('"email" or "username" property is required when initializing a ProjectUser object')
    }

    var self = this

    _.assign(self, ProjectEntity.call(self, obj))

    return self
}

util.inherits(ProjectUser, ProjectEntity)

module.exports = ProjectUser
```

#### Project ("singleton" but not really)

```
'use strict'

var ProjectClient = require('./lib/client')
var Project = {
    init: function(options) {
        var self = this
        if (self.isInitialized) {
            return self
        }
        Object.setPrototypeOf(Project, new ProjectClient(options))
        ProjectClient.call(self)
        self.isInitialized = true
    }
}

module.exports = Project
```

#### Client

```
var ProjectUser = require('./user'),
    _ = require('lodash')

var ProjectClient = function(options) {
    var self = this

    // some stuff happens here to check options and init with default values

    return self
}

ProjectClient.prototype = {
    GET: function() {
        return function() {
            // async GET request with callback
        }
    },
    PUT: function() {
        return function() {
            // async PUT request with callback
        }
    }
}

module.exports = ProjectClient
```

Comment: There's something wrong with `ProjectEntity` for sure. Are you overwriting it anywhere else?

Comment: I'm not overwriting or subclassing it anywhere else, but I am including it in a handful of places. Also of note I suppose is that I'm triggering this from some Mocha tests that include modules as well. I'll have to play around to see if it's related to how I'm using modules in my tests too o_O

Comment: You can see the source code for `inherits` [**here**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L791), it's just javascript. As you can see, the error is because there's no `prototype` property. After you comment out the `inherits` line you got an error saying that the reference isn't a function. So, at some point, `ProjectEntity` stops being a function and becomes something else.

Comment: Right, OK that makes sense. And it's not related to Mocha, because executing the `Entity` file directly behaves the same way.

Comment: So my thinking is that it's not that I'm clobbering Entity, but that I'm suffering from something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34079751/1214800. Somewhere in the nesting of modules, `module.exports` is being clobbered. I just don't know where or how to solve it.

Comment: Right, so i think i can see the circular dependency here, `Entity > Project > Client > User > Entity`, which means that `Entity` is still incomplete when it's loaded from `Client`.

Comment: Ugh, yeah. Thoughts on how to get it working?

Comment: I'll write it in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as you have correctly deducted there's a problem with a circular dependency. Your `Entity` module requires the `Project` Module which requires the `Client` module which requires the `User` Module which requires the `Entity` Module.

There's something you can do about it but it will depend on your starting point. If you require the `Project` module first then it should work with the code provided because the `Entity` module doesn't do anything with the `Project` module. Nothing has been exported on that module, so it's just an empty object. Then again, any source of errors on that module would be related on whatever exported objects are depended inside that module. So if you'd need the object with `init` inside `Entity` then there would be a problem.

You can export some methods/functions before initializing the dependency chain, which will make them available by then. Take the example of `NodeJS` docs:

> a.js

```
console.log('a starting');
exports.done = false;
var b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in a, b.done = %j', b.done);
exports.done = true;
console.log('a done');
```

> b.js

```
console.log('b starting');
exports.done = false;
var a = require('./a.js');
console.log('in b, a.done = %j', a.done);
exports.done = true;
console.log('b done');
```

> main.js

```
console.log('main starting');
var a = require('./a.js');
var b = require('./b.js');
console.log('in main, a.done=%j, b.done=%j', a.done, b.done);
```

So, `main.js` is the starting point. It requires `a.js` which immediately exports a `done` property and then requires `b.js`. `b.js` also exports a `done` property. The next line requires `a.js` which doesn't load `a.js` again but returns the exported properties so far (which includes the `done` property). At this point, `a` is incomplete but it has managed to give `b` enough to continue working. It's next line (on `b.js`) will print the exported property (a.done, which is false), then reset the exported property `done` to true. We are back on `a.js` in the `require('b.js')` line. `b.js` is now loaded completely and the rest is pretty easy to explain.

Output is:

```
main starting
a starting
b starting
in b, a.done = false
b done
in a, b.done = true
a done
in main, a.done=true, b.done=true
```

[**Here's**](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) the example, just in case you want to read the official docs.

Right, so point being... what can you do?

It's possible to export some things before initializing the dependency cycle, just so long as you don't actually need those dependencies. For example you can:

> a.js

```
exports.func = function(){ console.log('Hello world'); }
var b = require('./b.js');
console.log('a done');
```

> b.js

```
var a = require('./a.js');
a.func(); //i'm still incomplete but i got func!
console.log('b done');
```

You can't:

> a.js

```
b.func(); //b isn't even an object yet.
var b = require('./b.js');
console.log('a done');
```

> b.js

```
exports.func = function(){ console.log('hello world'); }
var a = require('./a.js');
a.func();
console.log('b done');
```

However, if your `a.js` module only exports functions then there's no real problem as long as these functions aren't being called somewhere else:

> a.js

```
exports.func = function(){ b.func(); }
var b = require('./b.js');
console.log('a done');
```

> b.js

```
exports.func = function(){ console.log('hello world'); }
var a = require('./a.js');
console.log('b done');
```

You are exporting a function that uses `b`, the function doesn't need to know about `b` right then, only when it's called. So both modules are being loaded correctly. If you are just exporting functions there's no problem with having the dependencies declared afterwards.

So you can require `a.js` from your main point and `func` will work correctly as the `b` reference points now to the complete `b.js` module. You can follow this pattern so long as you don't use the functions you export when loading the dependencies.

Comment: Bit of a convoluted process to parse through and figure out what I needed to do, but in the end, you got me thinking with exporting modules before the dependency chain is complete. This didn't actually work, but then I tried the opposite: loading modules _after_ the dependency chain was completed (e.g. loading some of the dependent modules inside the class's callback when it's actually used vs. immediately at the top of the file) -- this got things to work properly!

Comment: And with that, I'll definitely accept your answer, but it would be best if you could add in something about the way I solved it too so that future readers will be aware of both solutions.

Comment: You really are exporting modules before the dependency chain but you just took a different approach to loading the first module. You are letting the first module load completely and then resume the dependency chain through the function call. Basically, `A -> B -> C -> A`. `A` depends on `B` which depends on `C` which depends on `A`. You tricked `A` into thinking he didn't need `B` and `A` is now complete, then you loaded `B` which loaded `C` which used `A`.

Comment: MAN that is confusing. Thanks for making sense of the design behind it!

Comment: Very confusing. I honestly haven't thought out how it would play out to require any other entry point in the circular dependency. Like requiring `Entity` instead of `Project` for example.

Comment: If possible I'd reevaluate the dependencies and find a way to straighten them out.

Comment: Well, in this case I'm A) confined to some design decisions that aren't likely to change, but B) there isn't going to be any other supported entry point, so I think this will be suitable for now.